# Graphene nested queries

Tags: nested, graphene-python

I am trying to create a schema using graphene python and I'm stuck on what might be a simple problem.

I have 2 classes Products and Components and they have many2many relationship:

```py
    class Products():
        id = graphene.Int()
        name = graphene.String()
        customer_id = graphene.Int()
        linked_components = graphene.List(graphene.NonNull(lambda: Components))

    class Components():
        id = graphene.Int()
        name = graphene.String()
        linked_parts = graphene.List(graphene.NonNull(lambda: Products))

 def resolve_all_products(root, info, customer_id=None, limit=None, offset=None):
        domain = []
        if customer_id:
            domain.append(('customer_id', '=', customer_id))
        return info.context["env"]["product"].search(domain,
                                                        limit=limit, offset=offset
```

I need to query something like this

```
query myquery {
  allProducts(customerId: 8) {
    id
    name
    linkedComponents {
      id
      name
      linkedParts(customerId:8) {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

of Course it is not working this way and I am receiving error

> "message": "Unknown argument 'customerId' on field 'Components.linkedParts'.

How I can implemented nested query?

Answer (score 0):

So I just found answer thanks to https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/1025

basically i modified code following way:

```
 class Products():
    id = graphene.Int()
    name = graphene.String()
    customer_id = graphene.Int()
    linked_components = graphene.List(graphene.NonNull(lambda: Components))

class Components():
    id = graphene.Int()
    name = graphene.String()
    linked_parts = graphene.List(graphene.NonNull(lambda: Products), customer_id = graphene.Int())

def resolve_linked_parts(root, info,  **kwargs):
    customer_id =  kwargs.get('customer_id') or None
    return root.linked_part_id.search([('customer_id','=', customer_id)]) or None
```

def resolve_all_products(root, info, customer_id=None, limit=None, offset=None):
domain = []
if customer_id:
domain.append(('customer_id', '=', customer_id))
return info.context["env"]["product"].search(domain,
limit=limit, offset=offset

Hope it will be useful for someone else.